# react-intl: How can update child component without passing "this.props.intl"

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

When i change language object using intl library from parent component then i need to pass `intl={this.props.intl}` to child component for update. i am using `FormattedMessage id="example"` or `this.props.intl.formatMessage({ id: "example" })`. i have a chain of parent and child components. so i need to pass intl as props in every child or some component using multiple times. if i need to update child component then i need to pass intl in each and every child component. i need a solution. i don't want to pass this.props.intl in every child component.

Comment: Which version of React are you using?

Answer (score 0):

When you have to pass props through the chain of multiple childs, use context.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jnp233j539) is the CodeSandbox example.

Regarding when and how to use context, check [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), When you want to share something common to a component tree, you can use this.

Also please check https://hackernoon.com/how-do-i-use-react-context-3eeb879169a2